# Acces denied on com port c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I've been writing some code for a machine.
It has to talk RS485, and i can use normal serial communication for it, as is providedby .net

However since hardware can fail, i have to build in test routines.
So i wrote routine that re-detects available comports.
That populates a list 'allComPorts' with their string name, and a nummeric updown is then used to select the com port based upon its list index of the available comports. (yes this sounds a bit complex but for other reasons i had use a numeric updown for selections).

The problem is that this function woks only the first time.
If i call the function again i get an access denied as it seams already open. Tried  RS485Port.Close() at various places, but the problem then becomes it crashes if it hasnt been opened jet (a chicken egg problem).

My code to open a comport goes like this

```
    private void RS485Activate()
    {
            lblNoRS485Communication.Visible = false;
        if (cmbRS485Port.Value != 0) // if 0 then there are no serial ports
        {
            //rs485Port is a global declared as > System.IO.Ports.SerialPort RS485Port;
            RS485Port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(allComPorts[(int)cmbRS485Port.Value - 1]);
            if (!RS485Port.IsOpen)
            {
               // RS485Port.Close();
               // RS485Port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(allComPorts[(int)cmbRS485Port.Value - 1]);
                RS485Port.BaudRate = 9600;
                RS485Port.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;                 
                RS485Port.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;             
                RS485Port.DataBits = 8;                                        
                RS485Port.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;          
                RS485Port.RtsEnable = true;
                RS485Port.Open();  <== it crashes here with access denied
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is no COM port detected, the program will work but it cannot control any machinery", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            lblNoRS485Communication.Visible = true; // another warning
        }
     }
```

Comment: have you checked if the port is not used by another process?

Comment: well it has been opened before, by the same routine. but for the testing i can not assume this (othre things might have hapened to the machine).
and since i cannt test  like:  `if (RS485Port !=Null) RS485Port.close();` i wonder how to solve it

Comment: Calling Close() does not make the port available immediately.  There is a worker thread that needs to exit, the one that generates the DataReceived and ErrorReceived event.  How long that takes is unpredictable.  But you can certainly tell from the exception :)  Sleep for a while and try again.  Don't try forever since it might actually be another process that already claimed the port.

Answer (score 0):

I dont like the looks of this, so i hope there is a better way.
But as a work around, using a try catch construction its now first tried to close, (where the try-catch does protect against a close() error if it has not yet been initialized. Well i dont like this workaround, so better solutions are welcome, i don't think code should anticipate and be based on errors. (or is that ok these days with .net ?)

```
            //...                
            try
            { RS485Port.Close(); }
            catch
            { }
            RS485Port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(allComPorts[(int)cmbRS485Port.Value - 1]);
            if (!RS485Port.IsOpen)
            {
               // RS485Port.Close();
               // RS485Port = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(allComPorts[(int)cmbRS485Port.Value - 1]);
                RS485Port.BaudRate = 9600;
                RS485Port.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;          
                RS485Port.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;    
                RS485Port.DataBits = 8;                                      
                RS485Port.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;      
                RS485Port.RtsEnable = true;
                RS485Port.Open();
            }
```